# Invalid Literal for float():['1' error in python

Tags: python, file, som, uci

Code

```
    for i in range(num):
           # for j in range(4):
              lines = outf1.readline()
              brr[i]= list(map(float, lines.split()))
```

This is my input dataset

```
['1', '1.52101', '13.64', '4.49', '1.1', '71.78', '0.06', '8.75', '0', '0', '1']
['2', '1.51761', '13.89', '3.6', '1.36', '72.73', '0.48', '7.83', '0', '0', '1']
['3', '1.51618', '13.53', '3.55', '1.54', '72.99', '0.39', '7.78', '0', '0', '1']
```

I am working with SOM algorithm. I have a file containing float values having 4 or 5 decimal values. I need to retrieve these values and store to array.

Comment: Well, what would you expect `float("['1',")` to evaluate to? When you say that's your input dataset, do you mean that you have lists of strings, or strings that look like lists of strings, or ...? Where did `outf1` come from?

Comment: How the data is stored in file ? what is this input dataset you are talking about? as i can see you are not giving any thing as list.

Comment: See the link-->http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data...This is my dataset taken from UCI repository.List is brr[i].I have declared also the list as arr = [[0 for x in range(num)] for x in range(num)]

Comment: If you're actually opening that file into `outf1`, you should **not** be getting what you claim to get. Have you added `str` somewhere? Note you should `split(',')` - the elements are separated by commas, not whitespace. Provide a **[minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code** and the **full error traceback**.

Comment: I have already tried...arr[i]=map(float, lines.strip().split(','))..Still no change

Answer (score 1):

[`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should do the trick:

```
In [12]: line = "['1', '1.52101', '13.64', '4.49', '1.1', '71.78', '0.06', '8.75', '0', '0', '1']"

In [13]: map(float, ast.literal_eval(line))
Out[13]: [1.0, 1.52101, 13.64, 4.49, 1.1, 71.78, 0.06, 8.75, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be feeding `split` a line that starts with `['1'`, so of course that square bracked is going to be a problem.

The quick fix is to just `strip` each line (to make sure there's no whitespace), then remove first and last character to get rid of the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have tried arr[i]=map(float, lines.strip().split(','))..but still the same error persists

Comment: Can u suggest how to get rid of brackets...file contains the datasets with brackets..